# What type of test should be used?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, z-test

What kind of test would I use to find the answer to this?

Is there evidence that cereals promoted in an in-store circular have a higher average number of units sold per store than cereals not promoted in an in-store circular?

I was given data from a cereal company’s promotional statistics and asked to answer this. However, I’m unsure of which test to use.

Answer (score 0):

$z$-test is preferable when $n > 30$ and sample sizes are as equal as possible. Moreover, the variances in both groups should be equal (in addition to some other constraints.) If your sample size is less than 30, than you should consider $t$-test.

If you are useR, you could perform $t$-test using the `t.test()` function; before applying $t$-test you should perform $F$-test to test for equality of variances (e.g., with `var.test()` function).